# Public Google cloud project customers to see project and send request

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm struggling to set up my project to be visible to other customers and finally start earning money (currently, I have 0 customers). I've created multiple Google cloud support cases, but they always specialize only in one cloud application. I'm trying to understand the documentation, but I have a beginner's experience.So far, I've already created a Service Catalog. However, Google cloud support informed me that I need to create a Cloud Endpoint Open API, which I have started creating, but it's not yet finished, so it's not working at the moment. After that, I also need to set up the Asset Inventory, as mentioned in the documentation, to apply for Google cloud partner status. I've already created a Google Partner Advantage account and added a product there, but the main obstacle now is creating a Business Plan. I'm not sure what to choose and what information to include in the plan.Once the Business Plan is filled, sent, and accepted, the Google cloud Producer Portal will unlock for me. In my project, I'm using cloud storage, pub/sub, pub/sub lite, data store, data catalog, cloud functions, D L P (Data Loss Prevention), and security center. I hope this clarifies my situation, and I apologize for any misspellings.

user to see my product to send request to me and to start earn money

Comment: On Stack Overflow, one question/problem per post. Your post has no focus and no problem to solve other than to advise you to learn and understand the services, technology, and development processes. Your question is not suitable here. Please read this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).